# Python packet sniffer for local network

Tags: python, sockets, networking, network-programming, packet-sniffers

As the title says I am making a packet sniffer in python 2.7(needs to be 2.7 for compatibility purposes).

I got the functionality I wanted, sniffing all incoming or outgoing traffic that use TCP, UDP or ICMP with a code as follows:

`utils.py` is a module with the functions that parse each kind of package along with a few other auxiliary functions, the functions that create the socket are:

```
def socket_safe(*args):
    # Sets up a socket using the specified args, taking care of any exceptions
    # and returning the socket descriptor object
    try:
        sd = socket.socket(*args)
    except error, msg:
        print 'Error', msg[0], 'creating socket:', msg[0]
        sys.exit()
    return sd


def socket_universal():
    # Uses the socket_safe function to set up a socket object that will capture
    # any incoming or outgoing (including TCP, UDP and ICMP)
    # 0x0003 is ETH_P_ALL
    return socket_safe(socket.AF_PACKET , socket.SOCK_RAW , socket.ntohs(0x0003))
```

And the main file is this:

```
from struct import *
from socket import *
from utils  import *

eth_protocols = {'ip_protocol' : 8}

ip_protocols  = {'tcp_protocol'  : 6,
                 'icmp_protocol' : 1,
                 'udp_protocol'  : 17}

# Create a socket descriptor object that will receive any type of packet. 
# For details please see the function definition in utils.py
sd = socket_universal()

for _ in range(5):
    print 'WAITING FOR PACKET...'

    # Receive up to 65565 bytes of data from any available source
    # as a tuple of the form (packet_contents, source_socket_info)
    packet, \
    source  \
    = sd.recvfrom(65565)

    print 'PACKET RECEIVED : '

    # Parse the destination and source MAC addresses and the protocol from the ethernet header.
    # For details please see the function definition in utils.py
    dest_mac,    \
    src_mac,     \
    eth_protocol \
    = parse_ethernet_header(packet)

    print '\tETHERNET HEADER :                     \n', \
          '\t\tDestination MAC :', dest_mac,      '\n', \
          '\t\tSource MAC :     ', src_mac,       '\n', \
          '\t\tEth. Protocol :  ', eth_protocol


        # Parse IP packets
        if eth_protocol == eth_protocols['ip_protocol']:
            # Parse all available information from the IP header of the packet.
            # For details please see the function definition in utils.py
            version,         \
            ihl,             \
            type_of_service, \
            total_len,       \
            identification,  \
            ip_flags,        \
            offset,          \
            ttl,             \
            ip_protocol,     \
            ip_checksum,     \
            src_ip_addr,     \
            dest_ip_addr     \
            = parse_ip_header(packet)

            print '\tIP HEADER :                                 \n', \
                  '\t\tVersion :            ', version,         '\n', \
                  '\t\tIP Header Length :   ', ihl,             '\n', \
                  '\t\tType of Service :    ', type_of_service, '\n', \
                  '\t\tTotal Length :       ', total_len,       '\n', \
                  '\t\tIdentification :     ', identification,  '\n', \
                  '\t\tFlags :              ', ip_flags,        '\n', \
                  '\t\tOffset :             ', offset,          '\n', \
                  '\t\tTime to Live :       ', ttl ,            '\n', \
                  '\t\tIP Protocol :        ', ip_protocol,     '\n', \
                  '\t\tChecksum :           ', ip_checksum,     '\n', \
                  '\t\tSource Address :     ', src_ip_addr,     '\n', \
                  '\t\tDestination Address :', dest_ip_addr

            # Parse TCP packets 
            if ip_protocol == ip_protocols['tcp_protocol']:
                # Parse all available information from the TCP header of the packet.
                # For details please see the function definition in utils.py
                src_port,     \
                dest_port,    \
                seq_num,      \
                ack_num,      \
                data_offs,    \
                tcp_flags,    \
                window,       \
                tcp_checksum, \
                urg_ptr,      \
                data          \
                = parse_tcp_header(packet, ihl)

                print '\tTCP HEADER:                            \n', \
                      '\t\tSource Port :      ', src_port,     '\n', \
                      '\t\tDest Port :        ', dest_port,    '\n', \
                      '\t\tSequence Number :  ', seq_num,      '\n', \
                      '\t\tAcknowledgement :  ', ack_num,      '\n', \
                      '\t\tTCP header length :', data_offs,    '\n', \
                      '\t\tFlags :            ', tcp_flags,    '\n', \
                      '\t\tWindow :           ', window,       '\n', \
                      '\t\tChecksum :         ', tcp_checksum, '\n', \
                      '\t\tUrgen Pointer :    ', urg_ptr,      '\n', \
                      '\t\tData :             ', data 

            # Parse ICMP packets          
        elif ip_protocol == ip_protocols['icmp_protocol']:
            # Parse all available information from the ICMP header of the packet.
            # For details please see the function definition in utils.py
            icmp_type,     \
            code,          \
            icmp_checksum, \
            data           \
            = dataparse_icmp_header(packet, ihl)

                    print '\tIMCP HEADER :                  \n', \
                          '\t\tType :    ', icmp_type,     '\n', \
                          '\t\tCode :    ', code,          '\n', \
                          '\t\tChecksum :', icmp_checksum, '\n', \
                          '\t\tData :    ', data

        # Parse UDP packets
        elif ip_protocol == ip_protocols['udp_protocols']:
            src_port,     \
            dest_port,    \
            length,       \
            udp_checksum, \
            data          \
            = parse_udp_header(packet, ihl)

            print '\tUDP HEADER :                     \n', \
                  '\t\tSource Port :', src_port,     '\n', \
                  '\t\tDest Port :  ', dest_port,    '\n', \
                  '\t\tLength :     ', length,       '\n', \
                  '\t\tChecksum :   ', udp_checksum, '\n', \
                  '\t\tData :       ', data

        else:
            print '\tNOT A TCP, ICMP OR UDP PACKAGE. SKIPPING...' 


        print '\tEND OF PACKET.\n'
```

Now what I need to do it make it possible to only sniff packages in the local network.

If I needed only packages between certain machines i guess that could be resolved pretty quickly by using a list of IPs or MACs of the desired machines and a few `if`s, but I am not sure how exactly I am supposed to discern which packages represent traffic in a local network.

My guess is that I should use the `source` part of the `sd.recvfrom(65565)` as I saw the name what might be a newtork but the documentation on this is... simply not there, at least not in the official python documentation, no references to man pages or anything of that sort.

Bottom question is: how should I go about to restrict the 'sniffing' only to the local network?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The way ARP determines if the destination is on the same network is that it first determines the local network address by `AND`ing the local network address with the network mask. Then you can `AND` the destination address with the network mask, and if it matches the local network, it is a local network destination.

Comment: @RonMaupin Umm... "determines the local network address by `AND`ing the local network address with the network mask" to `AND` the  local network address with the network mask wouldn't you NEED to know these first?

Comment: You do know those. You know the local IP address and mask because they are configured on the interface, and you know the source and destination addresses because they are in the packet headers. You can get the network and mask when the application starts, and you can mask the packet source or destination address (depending on whether you are sniffing incoming or outgoing packets) to determine if the packets are from or to the local network.

Comment: @RonMaupin Since I'm rubbish at networking, I assume that what you mean by "network" in "You can get the network and mask when the application starts" is what you get in the `inet` field by popping `ifconfig` into a terminal(please correct me if I'm wrong), the mask is well... the `Mask` field.  

Now having those, if I wanted only packets that are meant for a destination in the local network I should `AND` the destination address part of the IP header with the network mask, and if the result is the  network address then the packet was meant for a host in the local network? Correct?

Comment: You should study the excellent answer to [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7106/8499). It explains how network addressing works, and you should be completely familiar with that before attempting such an endeavor. Network addresses are 32-bit binary numbers.

Comment: @RonMaupin I gave that answer a few reads as you said, and it was informative, it answered some things that I only knew intuitively. My question remains *almost* the same as in the previous comment with a small change:  if I wanted only packets that are meant for a host in the local network I should AND the destination address part of the IP header with the network mask, and if the result is an address between the first and last usable addresses then packet was meant for a host in the local network? Correct?

Comment: As I explained,You should get the network when the application starts, then you can get the network from the packets and do a comparison between the interface network and the packet network. You don't want to complicate things with first and last host addresses. With IPv4, you could send and receive broadcast traffic, too, and IPv6 can use all addresses in a network.

Comment: @RonMaupin Sorry, I think my problem is mapping theory to actual application, I assume that what you mean by "network" in "You can get the network and mask when the application starts" is what you get in the `inet` field by popping `ifconfig` into a terminal right? And where in the  packet header is the network? There is only source and destination IP

Comment: @RonMaupin I think I understand. Say if I want only local traffic, meaning packets from a local source to a local destination, i should `AND` the source and destination address from the IP header of a packet with the netMask, and see if they match the network address `AND` ed with the mask?  Is that correct?